# control the rotation of the particle instance to face to camera

Tags: particles

Hi i want to create a lot of tree using particle . I create a master tree where it's just a simple plane and i used a tree image (with alpha channel) as the material. Then i create another plane (as ground) and apply particle system modifier and select my master tree as the instance object. Now i want to contol the rotation of the instance to always face the current camera position. is it possible ?

Comment: did you try with Drivers?

Comment: Look into animation nodes for more control instead of the current particle system

Answer (score 4):

Thanks CG Boost: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLVodLos41Q

Here is a summary:

1. Create an Empty that you parent to your camera but placed far away behind it on the local Z axis. This will be used to lock the particle source orientation that will "look" at that general direction
    [image]
2. place the source particle object somewhere in the middle of where most particles will be (in the middle of the forest)
3. Add a `Track to` Constraint to the source particle object, use the empty behind the camera as target
4. Add a `Limit Rotation` constraint to the same object to keep it strait.
    [image]

This way, generated particles should all face the general direction of the camera as long as the empty is far enough behind it.

[image]

Also if you have trouble with your source object in the middle of your scene, just put it on a difference scene along with a linked duplicate of the camera.